# When i am trying to insert data into table, getting error

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I created page using laravel for fetching data from the database, into the table. In the same page i am given option to insert data to the database. when am inserting data to the database, its showing error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `device` (`vehicleID`) values (avs))". Previously it was working properly and i able to insert the datas.
My view page is giving below

```
   @extends('app')

@section('content')



    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
        <div class="templatemo-content">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
                <li class="active">Vehicle information</li>
            </ol>
            <h1>View/Edit Vehicle information</h1>

            <p></p>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x:auto;">

                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" bgcolor="#fff8dc">
                            <h3>Select a Vehicle :</h3>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Vehicle ID</th>
                                <th>Unique ID</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Equipment Type</th>
                                <th>SIM Phone</th>
                                <th>Server ID</th>
                                <th>Ignition State</th>
                                <th>Expecting ACK</th>
                                <th>Active</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($devices as $device)
                            <tr>

                            <td>{{ $device->vehicleID }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->uniqueID }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->equipmentType }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $device->simPhoneNumber }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                @if(@$device->ignitionIndex == '0')
                                    OFF
                                    @else
                                ON
                                    @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $device->expectAck }}</td>
                            <td>
                                @if($device->isActive == '1')
                                    Yes
                                @else
                                    No
                                @endif
                            </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Action</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                                            <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acceptModal" data-bookingid="{{ $device->vehicleID }}"><a href="#">View/ Edit</a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li><a href="{{ url('/vehicle/delete/'.$device->vehicleID)}}">Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{--{!! $results->appends(['sort' => $sort])->render() !!}--}}

                        {{$devices->links()}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{--{!! $device->links()!!}--}}


    </br>

    <h4>Create a new Vehicle</h4>
    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('vehicleAdmin') }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom-15">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vehicleID" value="{{ old('vehicleID') }}" placeholder="Enter vehicle ID">
            </div>
            <div class="row templatemo-form-buttons">
                <div class="submit-button">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
    </script>
@endsection
```

controller page is

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Device;
use App\Http\Requests\createUserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class VehicleController extends Controller
{
    public $type = 'Device';





    public function getIndex()
    {


        $devices = DB::table('device')->simplePaginate(15);
        return view('vehicle.vehicleAdmin')->with('devices', $devices);
    }


    public function vehicleInsert()
    {
        $postUser = Input::all();
        //insert data into mysql table
        $data =      array('vehicleID'=> $postUser['vehicleID']
        );
        //  echo print_r($data);
        $ck = 0;
        $ck = DB::table('device')->Insert($data);
        //echo "Record Added Successfully!";
        $devices = DB::table('device')->simplePaginate(50);
        return view('vehicle.vehicleAdmin')->with('devices', $devices);


    }


    public function delete($id)
    {
        DB::table('device')->where('vehicleID', '=', $id)->delete();
        return redirect('vehicleAdmin');
    }

}
```

and the route page is

```
 Route::any('vehicleAdmin', 'VehicleController@getIndex');
Route::post('vehicleAdmin', 'VehicleController@vehicleInsert');
Route::delete('vehicle/delete/{id}', 'VehicleController@delete');
```

Can any one tell me why this error is coming, and what i need to do?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

i think vehicleID is auto-increment and no need to insert

```
public function vehicleInsert()
{
    $postUser = Input::all();
    //insert data into mysql table 
    $data =      array('other-columns'=> $postUser['other-columns']
    );
    //  echo print_r($data);
    $ck = 0;
    $ck = DB::table('device')->Insert($data);
    //echo "Record Added Successfully!";
    $devices = DB::table('device')->simplePaginate(50);
    return view('vehicle.vehicleAdmin')->with('devices', $devices);


}
```

Comment: vehicle id is not auto incremented one

Comment: yeah, am inserting different value only, but still its showing same error